# Understanding Memory Addresses in C++

Tags: c++

Why doesn't the address change as I increment str? I thought that when I performed pointer arithmetic, the pointer points to a different memory address. Therefore, shouldn't the memory address change as well?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

void reverse(char* str){
    cout << &str << endl;

    while(*str != '\0'){
        cout << &str << endl;
        str++; 
    }
}


int main(){

    char str[] = "hello"; 
    reverse(str); 

}
```

Comment: You are printing the address of the pointer that is storing the address - that is a `char **`

Comment: Perhaps `cout << (void *)str << endl;` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&str` is the address of the pointer. You are changing the pointer as you iterate over the characters, but the pointer that you are changing is still located at the same spot.

Edit: change your `cout << &str << endl;` to `cout << "pointer loc<" << &str << "> pointer value<" << (void*)str << ">" << endl;` and see what it says.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. That makes sense. I am getting the address of the pointer that points to the value stored. However, what does (void*)str mean? Or could you point me to some resource so that I can understand this?

Comment: @Jae That is a casting operator (it's actually a C-style cast to be specific, which is something you generally shouldn't do... shame on me). It tells the compiler to treat a piece of data with a certain data type as if it has a different data type. A `void*` is basically is a pointer to a memory address where the data type is undefined. Before casting it, it was a `char*` and `cout` would have realized that and output the entire string at that location (kept on outputting until it hit a '\0'). As a `void*` it won't interpret it that way, and will print the value at that memory address.

Comment: @Jae `std::ostream` has an overloaded `operator <<` that recognizes `char*` as strings, and prints them. If you want the actual value of the pointer,  you must cast it to `void*`.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. Somebody said this before and I didn't quite understand what he meant by "std::ostream has an overloaded operator <<".  Could you please clarify?